# C# ClientWebSocket возвращает ошибку "The WebSocket request or response contained unsupported header(s)."

Tags: c#, unity3d, исключения, websocket, uri

написал на Unity3D тулзу для подключения к серверу по websocket, для этого использую библиотеку **System.Net.WebSockets.** Собрал билд под Android, закинул в плей маркет, бот там проверил оттестировал и все спокойно подключается к серверу, так же я на своем андройд планшете проверил, в эмуляторах и в самой юнити.
Проблема заключается в том, что некоторые устройства (например мой смартфон) попросту не хотят подключаться по вебсокету, при попытке коннекта выдают ошибку **"The WebSocket request or response contained unsupported header(s)."** Что за магия такая, почему часть устройств подключается, а часть нет? Опытным путем было выяснено что проблема заключается в Uri. Я пробовал сменить библиотеку сокетов на другую где при коннекте можно использовать просто string с адресом вида "ws://127.0.0.1:28020/password" и те устройства которые не коннектились через Uri смогли приконектиться. Но мне нужно заставить библиотеку System.Net.WebSockets работать, помогите разобраться, ниже приведу код примера подключения.

```
ClientWebSocket socket = new ClientWebSocket();
string ip = "127.0.0.1";
string port = "28020";
string password = "myPass123";
uri = new Uri($"ws://{ip}:{port}/{password}");
await socket.ConnectAsync(uri, cancellationTokenSource.Token);
```

Answer (score 0):

В моем случае, проблема была с сервером который не осуществил нормально HANDSHAKE для перехода с HTTP/1.1 на websocket.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_servers

Comment: В моем случае, сервера абсолютно одинаковые к которым хочу коннектится, разница была лишь в том что сервер стоял на разных физических машинах, т.е скорее всего проблема не была в коде клиента вебсокета. В общем проблему так и не удалось решить, некоторые устройства (клиент) отказывался коннектится к некоторым серверам (физическим) и выдавал ошибку об заголовках.